# How to check if my laptop is thunderbolt 3 enabled?

Tags: laptop, usb, thunderbolt

I just bought a recent ASUS laptop.

The seller clearly stated on its website that this laptop USB type-C connector was "thunderbolt 3" compatible.

Since, my USB connector doesn't have the usual little lightning logo, I'm having doubt that's this connector is really "Thunderbolt 3"...
It's clear however that the connector is USB 3.1 Gen2

I'm still confused with the different types of USB type-C connector so I would like to check if my laptop has the hardware required to be "thunderbolt 3" enabled,

According to this [article](https://thunderbolttechnology.net/blog/thunderbolt%E2%84%A2-3-controllers-launch-6th-gen-intel%C2%AE-core%E2%84%A2-processors-ifa-show), my laptop should have a dedicated controller for thunderbolt, but how to be sure?

Any help appreciated..

Comment: It should be somewhere under the PCI Bus in Device Manager. I am not sure though.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I noticed nothing special neither in the PCI bus neither in the USB controller... I saw on the Intel forum that a quick mean would be to connect a thunderbolt device, but I don't have it... yet...

Comment: might help to mention the model in case its in the manual

Comment: Thanks for your help, it's an ASUS N752VX-GC128T. I checked on the ASUS manual but it's not specified. I sent an email to Asus as well and I'm still waiting for the answer.

Comment: Dosen't seem to turn up in lshw or device monitor on my razer blade stealth. Release notes for the thunderbolt manager software preinstalled on my system indicates they're powered down until they're in use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a way to verify the thunderbolt compatibility of a computer:

- If the laptop is really Thunderbolt enabled, there should be a line in the different *"BIOS setup options"* mentioning "Thunderbolt" somewhere  (*or maybe "Alpine Ridge" for the host controller codename*)
- If there is no mention of Thunderbolt in the BIOS, then it's likely that your
  computer is not Thunderbolt enabled..

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a fairly old thread, but I have been looking for a definitive answer myself, as the specs for my HP 850 G5 just say Thunderbolt - ditto for all the details I could find in Device Manager.

Eventually I came across the freeware HWiNFO64 at hwinfo.com, and found the information I wanted ("Thunderbolt 3 Bridge") under the Bus heading. It will also tell you whether you have 2 or 4 PCI-E lanes (I only have two it seems, ho hum!).

Answer (score 1):

On windows machine you can run dxdiag.exe. From there you can save a text file with all you installed HW/drivers,...

Then look for thunderbold in the text.
Something like:

```
Name: Thunderbolt(TM) Controller - 15EB
Device ID: PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_15EB&SUBSYS_08311028&REV_06\C4520491CDB7D00000
   Driver: C:\WINDOWS\system32\DRIVERS\tbt100x.sys, 17.04.0079.0011 (English), 12/30/2018 08:38:22, 137680 bytes
   Driver: C:\Intel\Thunderbolt\setup.msi, 1/7/2019 14:28:28, 8798208 bytes
   Driver: C:\WINDOWS\system32\tbtcoinx_17_4_79_11.dll, 17.04.0079.0011 (English), 12/30/2018 08:38:24, 411600 bytes
```

Comment: I just ran DxDiag, but the .txt file doexn't mention thunderbolt although I have thunderbolt 3

Answer (score 1):

Hunt down your laptop specifications online for detailed specifications. For instance a [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=hp%2015-eg0073cl%20specs) on "HP 15-eg0073cl specs" leads to a page that says:

**External Ports**

- SuperSpeed USB Type-C® 10Gbps signaling rate (USB Power Delivery, DisplayPort™ 1.4)
- 2 SuperSpeed USB Type-A 5Gbps signaling rate
- 1 HDMI 2.0

Lack of Thunderbolt port is confirmed, however USB-C to DisplayPort 1.4 monitor should work.

Answer (score 1):

I ran msinfo32.exe and found mention of 'Thunderbolt' in 2 spots.
a) Under: System>Hardware Resources>IRQ
b) Under: System>Software Environment>System Drivers

You can also search for the word 'Thunderbolt' using msinfo32.exe

[image: IRQ for Thunderbolt]
[image: Driver for Thunderbolt]

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if this is definitive, but my Dell Latitude 5401 which has Thunderbolt has this shown in the Device Manager. Maybe that might help someone:
[Screen shot of device manager showing "Thunderbolt HSA Component"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zXwCj.png)

Answer (score -2):

My system came with a thunderbolt software or installed.
It's called Thunderbolt Software and it lists the ports available.